# wp_login_url always redirects me to wp-admin

Tags: php, redirect, login

I have a specific site on my website which needs to be logged in.
So if I visit the page and I am not logged in, I want to redirected to `wp-login`and back to the page. But everything I am trying, I will always redirected to `wp-admin`

That is one of my failures:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', [ $this, 'redirect_to_login_page' ] );
```

```
public function redirect_to_login_page() {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/test' ) !== false ) {
            $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', site_url( '/test' ), wp_login_url() );
            wp_redirect( $login_url );
            exit;
        }
    }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

this code on functions.php should work or using this code on a plugin or in a snippet.
Just change the 'yourpage' to your respective page and the link on the wp_redirect function.

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_if_user_is_logged' );

function custom_if_user_is_logged(){
    if(is_page('yourpage') && !is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_redirect('https://your_website.net/wp-admin');
    }
}
```

also when is a normal page from wordpress its possible to use this bellow instead of the is_page('yourpage'):

is_home() : Home Page

is_front_page :  Front Page

is_single() :  Single Post

is_admin() : Admin Panel

is_sticky() : Sticky Post

is_page() : Page

is_category

is_tag

is_author